# Kotlin meta programming with variables

Tags: java, android, kotlin, metaprogramming, font-awesome

I'm creating an app with a dynamic bottom navigation menu. The `title` and `icon_name` of each menu item comes from an API call.

I've managed to read the JSON into an array of models called `AppNavigation` and I now want to customize the bottom navigation icons and titles.

For titles it was a simple matter of doing this

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_one).title = sqlAppNavigations[0].name
```

But the icons are proving much more difficult. I have the icon name which looks like `fa_home` or `fa_users`. I need to take this string value and use it to get the icon from a big enum of all FontAwesome icons.

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_one).icon = FontAwesomeIcons.fa_home)
```

In Ruby on Rails I'd use the `FontAwesomeIcons.send('fa_home')` but I don't know how the same thing is accomplished in Kotlin (or if it's even possible with a compiled language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Enum has a couple of implicit methods, one of which is what I believe you are looking for: `EnumClass#valueOf(String)`

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_one).icon = FontAwesomeIcons.valueOf(sqlAppNavigations[0].icon)
```

[Working with Enum Constants](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants)